# React Native: fail while installing the "app". Error at executing gradlew.bat

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

​Well, I am trying to install all components to run React Native apps on my computer, but I have been working on this for four days and I always got the same error message:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

​I reinstalled the components three times, but only some things changed, like the time that jumped from **30 minutes** to **3 hours**, and the quantity of text that shows on my screen.

​I tried a lot of solutions I found on the internet, like uninstall the global `react-native-cli` and use `.\gradlew clean` however it did not work because I got a message saying that **"."** is not recognized like a command. I really do not know how to correct it...

#### Bellow, my computer configurations:

- **System:** *Windows 7 professional SP1*
- **Processor:** *Intel Atom CPU D525 @1.80Ghz 1.79GHz*
- **RAM memory:** *2,00GB*
- **Type of system:** *32-bit operating system*

#### The React Native component versions I installed:

- **Chocolatey:** *v0.10.15*
- **Node.js:** *v12.13.0*
- **Npm:** *6.12.0*
- **Yarn:** *1.22.5*
- **Python:** *2.7.18*
- **JDK 8:** *1.8.0_271*
- **Android Studio:** *3.6.3*

#### Observations:

- I also have **Python 3.8** installed
- I also tried the *command line tools only* before the *Android Studio IDE*

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
  android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
  at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:413)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2418)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:907)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:158)
  at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:22015)
  at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
  at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2809)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4070)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
  at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:232)
  at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:148)
  at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:163)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:510)
  at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:411)
  ... 10 more

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1h 47m 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\appproject1\android\app\src\debug\java\com\appproject1\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\appproject1>
```

​   I apologize for not being able to give you more information. I ask you to help me, please.

#### Edit:

I would like to give some tips about problems I got when trying to use react-native:

- **Low space on the smartphone**. Please try to install something in the store, if you cannot do it, you need to free some space.
- Some problems could be solved only by trying to **run the project by Android Studio**, please try it too.
- **Cache may be your problem**. Try it inside the project folder:

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```

after it, run the project again returning to the project folder using `cd ..`:

```
cd ..
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue:

```
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
```

solution -1-
replace

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

with

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

solution -2-

```
make some space on the device / emulator
```

Comment: Yes, I did not see it when I reading the error message and I would never think that my low space would be one of the problems, I had almost 1gb free. I also noticed after it that I had problems with cache too. Thank you for your help!